# Java: Why is this loop throwing me a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

In the following sample code, I'm moving through two large arrays, 40,000+ indices, of x and y coordinates. However, I'm being thrown the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` upon reaching the final index - as I've deduced with much testing. I'm aware that this exception is thrown when referring to an index that's out of bounds, however, I don't think I'm referring to any out of bounds indices. Furthermore, it seems as if this exception is only being thrown on certain computers. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(screenWidth, screenHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size()-1;){
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size()-1;){
        g2d.setColor(col);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
              RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
              RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.drawLine(arrayList.get(i),
                  arrayList2.get(j),
                  arrayList.get(i+1),
                  arrayList2.get(j+1));
        i++;    
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: You can include your increment expressions in the for loop parenthesis, if that helps alleviate confusion.

Comment: This is why you should use for loops properly, with your index incrementation at the top of the loop where it belongs. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I apologize for not explaining previously in my context, however, due to the actual project I'm coding, it's necessary to iterate through the lists at the same time, not through all of the first one and then the second one, if that makes any more sense. Sorry!

Comment: No, that makes no sense at all, and again is the reason for your bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are incrementing `i` in the inner loop, instead of after the inner loop completes.

The following code should behave better:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size()-1; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size()-1; ++j){

        g2d.setColor(col);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
              RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
              RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.drawLine(arrayList.get(i), arrayList2.get(j), arrayList.get(i+1), arrayList2.get(j+1));
    }
}
```

If `arrayList` has 10 elements, and `arrayList2` has 20 elements, then your code will iterate the inner loop 19 times.  On each run of the inner loop, you will increment both `i` and `j`.  After the tenth iteration of the inner loop, then `i` and `j` both equal 10, and the code `arrayList.get(i+1)` will fail.

Comment: Yes! That's awesome - Thank you so much!